# Using unordered_map of C++0x

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, unordered-map

I am using an `unordered_map` which is included as:
`#include <unordered_map>`
and the program is compiled as follows:
`g++ Test.cc -std=gnu++0x -o test`
Am I using the `unordered_map` of TR1 or that of C++0x. Or is it both the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe gcc puts their TR1 headers in `<tr1/unordered_map>`, so you should be getting the C++11 version.  But they are very similar.

Comment: I confirm for gcc 4.5.2 (mingw port, if that matters).

Answer (score 3):

GCC has tr1 headers in tr1 subdirectory.  Plus there is the tr1 namespace.

```
#include <tr1/unordered_map>
...
std::tr1::unordered_map<...>(...);
```

So unless you specifically did these things or did a similar "using" you've got the std ones.

The implementations are split but they are rather similar.  There were just enough differences (initializer_list, comparison ops) to make maintenance of one file with all the conditionals and macros a pain.

Answer (score 0):

This depends very much on the particular compiler version. For instance, GCC 4.4 basically just had some macro switches for your `-std=c++0x` option to do the namespace labelling appropriately, but would always end up pulling the actual code from `tr1_impl/unordered_map`, while GCC 4.6 has two entirely separate implementations, one in `tr1/unordered_map.h` and one in `bits/unordered_map.h` -- and the respective base class implementations in `.../hashtable.h` do in fact differ; the C++0x version has `std::forward`s everywhere etc.

Short answer: It depends.